# How to merge multiple files once multiprocessing has ended in Python?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, file-writing, file-processing

In my code, multiprocessing Process is being used to spawn multiple impdp jobs (imports) simultaneously and each job generates a log file with the dynamic name:

> '/DP_IMP_' + DP_PDB_FULL_NAME[i] + '*' + DP_WORKLOAD  +  '*' + str(vardate) + '.log'

```
vardate = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y-%I_%M_%S_%p")
tempfiles = []
for i in range((len(DP_PDB_FULL_NAME))):
        for DP_WORKLOAD in DP_WORKLOAD_NAME:
                 tempfiles.append(logdir + '/DP_IMP_' + DP_PDB_FULL_NAME[i] + '_' + DP_WORKLOAD  +  '_' + str(vardate) + '.log')
                 p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=imp_workload, args=(DP_WORKLOAD, DP_DURATION_SECONDS, vardate, ))
                 p1.start()
```

I want to merge all the log files created into one large master log file once all the processes have ended. But, when I am trying to use something like this under the (for i in range((len(DP_PDB_FULL_NAME))) loop:

```
with open('DATAPUMP_IMP_' + str(vardate) + '.log','wb') as wfd:
    for f in tempfiles:
        with open(f,'rb') as fd:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)
```

then it's trying to write the files before the processes end.

Here, DP_PDB_FULL_NAME is a list of multiple databases so multiple processes are spawning simultaneously in multiple DBs. When I try to add `p1.join()` after the loop ends then the multiprocessing is not happening in multiple DBs.

So, how should I create a master log file once all the individual processes are completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create some kind of structure where you store the needed variables and process handles. Block with [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) after that loop until all subprocesses are finished and then work with the resulted files.

```py
handles = []
for i in range(10):
    p = Process()
    p.start()
    handles.append(p)

for handle in handles:
    handle.join()
```

Comment: When I tried to add p1.join() right after p1.start() then the multiprocessing is not working. Where are you suggesting should I add the join?

Answer (score 0):

So, I added the `p1.join()` after the first loop ended and now it's working!

```
vardate = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y-%I_%M_%S_%p")
tempfiles = []
for i in range((len(DP_PDB_FULL_NAME))):
        for DP_WORKLOAD in DP_WORKLOAD_NAME:
                 tempfiles.append(logdir + '/DP_IMP_' + DP_PDB_FULL_NAME[i] + '_' + DP_WORKLOAD  +  '_' + str(vardate) + '.log')
                 p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=imp_workload, args=(DP_WORKLOAD, DP_DURATION_SECONDS, vardate, ))
                 p1.start()
p1.join()

with open('DATAPUMP_IMP_' + str(vardate) + '.log','wb') as wfd:
    for f in tempfiles:
        with open(f,'rb') as fd:
```

To explain it further, there are three cases for adding the join in the above scene and multiprocessing works accordingly.

1. Inside the innermost for-loop:

   So, if join is added here, then the multiprocessing won't work at all because it's just after the proc.start()

```
for i in range((len(DP_PDB_FULL_NAME))):
        for DP_WORKLOAD in DP_WORKLOAD_NAME:
                 tempfiles.append(logdir + '/DP_IMP_' + str(vardate) + '.log')
                 p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=imp_workload, args=(DP_WORKLOAD, ))
                 p1.start()
                 p1.join()
```

2. Inside the outer for loop (outside the innermost for-loop)

   Here, multiprocessing works just for the inner loop and not in multiple DBs

```
for i in range((len(DP_PDB_FULL_NAME))):
        for DP_WORKLOAD in DP_WORKLOAD_NAME:
                 tempfiles.append(logdir + '/DP_IMP_' + str(vardate) + '.log')
                 p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=imp_workload, args=(DP_WORKLOAD, ))
                 p1.start()
        p1.join()
```

3. Outside the outer for-loop

   This is the correct solution (mentioned above) where it is outside all the loops that is using multiprocessing.

Comment: This works, but there is one crucial problem. Currently you are always calling join only for the last initialized subprocess. If it finishes faster than previous processes, you might face again the initial problem - losing data. I'll add an edit for you

Comment: @potato_cannon yeah, you are right. I am facing the exact problem. so, how do you suggest I make the changes?

Comment: I edited the accepted answer for clarification